# Plot coefficients depending on their significance

Tags: r, linear-regression

I try to visualize the significance of each variable/combination of a DiD model.

```
attach(mtcars)
M=lm(mpg ~ hp + wt * gear , data =mtcars)
summary(M)

coef(M)
confint(M, level = 0.9)
```

Therefore I want to create a barplot to list the (most) significant coefficients in a sorted order. The `summary(M)` command lists the coefficients and the corresponding significance codes. Each coefficient with a high significance code (***) should be listend first, then the ** and then the *. The dot and '' should not be included.

So, first of all, how could I get the corresponding significance codes/values of each coefficient. And how can I include/exclude the coefficients depending on the significance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before I answer this question, I want to question part of its premise. I would argue that it's best **not** to dichotomize (trichotomize) effects based on whether they fall on one side or the other of a conventional threshold -- if you really need to do this, I would suggest colouring (as shown below).  Please, please, please don't [suppose that the difference between 'significant' and 'not significant' is statistically significant](http://andrewgelman.com/2013/01/09/the-difference-between-significant-and-non-significant-is-not-itself-statistically-significant/) ...

```
## never attach if you can help it! attach(mtcars)
M <- lm(mpg ~ hp + wt * gear , data=mtcars)
```

`coef(summary(M))` pulls out the coefficient table, which is what we want to work with. We will also rearrange it for convenience:

```
efftab <- function(model) {
     ss <- coef(summary(model))
     ss <- data.frame(var=rownames(ss),ss,
          stringsAsFactors=FALSE)  ## add variable names
     rownames(ss) <- NULL ## cosmetic
     ss <-  ss[-1,]  ## generally makes sense to drop the intercept
     names(ss)[5] <- "pval"    ## rename
     ## p-value categories
     ss$pval_cat <- cut(ss$pval,c(0,0.001,0.01,0.05,0.1,1),
                labels=c("***","**","*",".","_"))
     ss <- ss[order(ss$pval),]  ## order by p-value
     ss
}
```

Try it out:

```
print(ss <- efftab(M),digits=3)
##       var Estimate Std..Error t.value    pval pval_cat
## 2      hp  -0.0335    0.00962  -3.486 0.00169       **
## 4    gear   5.3656    2.44437   2.195 0.03693        *
## 5 wt:gear  -1.4791    0.78439  -1.886 0.07013        .
## 3      wt   1.7814    2.76202   0.645 0.52439        _


library("plotrix")
colvec <- c("red","orange","blue","gray","white")

par(las=1,bty="l")
with(ss,plotCI(1:4,Estimate,1.96*Std..Error,pch=23,cex=3,
       pt.bg=colvec[pval_cat],axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="estimate"))
axis(side=2)
axis(side=1,at=1:4,ss$var)
abline(h=0,lty=2)
```

[image]

However, this would make more sense if we standardized the variables (see Schielzeth 2010 *Methods in Ecology and Evolution*), so that differences in magnitude of coefficients actually represents differences in effect, rather than a confounding between the effect size and the units the variable is measured in:

```
scdat <- mtcars
vars <- c("mpg","hp","wt","gear")
scdat[vars] <- scale(as.matrix(scdat[vars]),center=FALSE)
M2 <- update(M,data=scdat)
ss2 <- efftab(M2)
with(ss2,plotCI(1:4,Estimate,1.96*Std..Error,pch=23,cex=3,
       pt.bg=colvec[pval_cat],axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="estimate"))
axis(side=2)
axis(side=1,at=1:4,ss$var)
abline(h=0,lty=2)
```

For example,

- the `wt:gear` interaction has about the same effect on mpg as `gear` (although you do need to be careful comparing interaction terms with main effects -- another potential can of worms), even though p<0.05 for `gear` and p>0.05 for `wt:gear`.
- `hp` has the *smallest* effect on `mpg` (or maybe tied with the not-nearly-significant effect of `wt`), even though it has the smallest p-value.

[image]

Comment: Outstanding answer Ben! Great advice on both programming and data analysis.

Comment: Just wow! Thank you very much! I think thats more than expected. I have to think about it, if there are questions, I will comment here. Thanks a lot!